# Making interface settings stick on SmoothWall

Tags: smoothwall

I have a SmoothWall Express 3.0 with a NIC on which I need to force full duplex because for some reason it and our ISP's equipment cannot auto negotiate. I do this by ethtool, but whenever I reboot the SmoothWall the settings are lost. Where can I put these settings so they stick?

Comment: Which version of SmoothWall? I will try and find out for you.

Comment: SmoothWall express 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the calls to ethtool in /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit, which appears to work.